# Cpanel update python and install pip

Tags: python, server, cpanel

I've been working in a project in Laravel using a AI model in python.
The problem I've been facing is:

- that I need to update the python from 2.7 to 3.6 and install pip
  because I use same modules to make it work.
- Another issue is that I
  need to do this without restarting the server, because that are other websites related to it.

Can anyone tell me how shall I deal with it?
Thanks in advance